Duplicating the list of fields from one object to a new object
I am a beginner in Salesforce APEX.
Recently, I have been newly assigned to configure the Salesforce environment at my company.
I originally worked in service operations and only know basic coding theory without any practical experience.
There is currently no one in my company with expertise in Salesforce, so I have been assigned to this task.
What I want to do is to transfer the fields of the existing object exactly as they are to a new object. The purpose of doing this is to eventually migrate the data to the new object. Therefore, I asked ChatGPT and received the following APEX class code, but I encountered an error as shown in the image and the class could not be saved. It is not easy to find the cause, and I have no understanding of the Metadata API. I would appreciate it if you could help.
public class FieldDuplicator {
public void duplicateFields(String sourceObjectName, String targetObjectName) {
    // Step 1: Retrieve fields from the source object
    List<Schema.SObjectField> fields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sourceObjectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().values();

    // Step 2: Prepare Metadata for the new fields
    List<MetadataService.CustomField> newFields = new List<MetadataService.CustomField>();

    for (Schema.SObjectField field : fields) {
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = field.getDescribe();

        // Skip standard fields or any fields you don't want to duplicate
        if (fieldDescribe.isCustom()) {
            MetadataService.CustomField newField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
            newField.fullName = targetObjectName + '.' + fieldDescribe.getName();
            newField.label = fieldDescribe.getLabel();
            newField.type_x = fieldDescribe.getType().name().toLowerCase();
            newField.length = fieldDescribe.getLength();
            newField.precision = fieldDescribe.getPrecision();
            newField.scale = fieldDescribe.getScale();
            newField.required = fieldDescribe.isNillable() ? false : true;

            newFields.add(newField);
        }
    }

    // Step 3: Create the new fields using the Metadata API
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

    List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.createMetadata(newFields);
    for (MetadataService.SaveResult result : results) {
        if (result.success) {
            System.debug('Successfully created: ' + result.fullName);
        } else {
            for (MetadataService.Error error : result.errors) {
                System.debug('Error: ' + error.message);
            }
        }
    }
}

}


I've heard it said that ChatGPT (and similar tools) is good at filling small gaps in knowledge (giving just the last little push, or surfacing some insight that was unknown or initially disregarded), but is not suitable for situations like this where you're starting to build knowledge.

Trying to dive into the Metadata API is definitely throwing yourself into the deep end of the pool. This is not something that's reasonable to expect from someone with no experience with Salesforce.
ChatGPT did you dirty here, and this is a prime example of why it's not really a good idea for beginners to use it. It's just too tempting to use it as a crutch, and you don't have the requisite knowledge to know when it's producing wrong or incomplete (or hallucinated) information.
I'd use the Salesforce CLI to accomplish this task
While you could use the Metadata API (using Apex) within an org, when it comes time to move changes from a scratch org or a sandbox to your production org, you'll likely be using The Salesforce CLI (a.k.a. Salesforce DX).
https://trailhead.salesforce.com is generally the place to start learning about Salesforce things, and there is a trail specific to getting the currently supported toolset up and running (which includes parts about the Salesforce CLI).
Once you get that set up and have a SFDX Project (sf project generate -n <some name here>), you'd:

Pull the two SObjects and their fields, sf project retrieve start -m CustomObject:<your first object's API name> CustomObject:<your second object's API name>

The "API name" has no spaces in it (underscores are used instead) and will pretty much always end in __c. Standard Objects like Account, Contact, Opportunity, Asset, etc... do not end in __c. All of your custom SObjects and custom fields (on any SObject, standard or custom) will end in __c


Navigate to ./force-app/main/default/objects/<first object label>
Go into the "fields" subfolder, select all of your fields and copy them
Navigate to ./force-app/main/default/objects/<second object label>, get into the "fields" subfolder, and paste the field metadata that you copied
Use the Salesforce CLI to deploy those copied fields, sf project deploy start -m CustomObject:<your second object's API name>

Gotchas

There may be some fields that you can't directly copy like this. Mainly stuff like standard relationship and address fields (so you couldn't copy the OpportunityId field from OpportunityLineItem). You'd probably need to recreate those by hand in Salesforce's Web UI (i.e. the Salesforce website for your org). Editing the field metadata to add __c at the end of the text inside the <fullName> tag may work.
Field permissions (Field Level Security, FLS) are separate from the field itself, and those do not get deployed. You will need to set up the FLS. It's a tedious process. Using a PermissionSet is probably the way to go here (still tedious, but it's ideally something you'd only need to go through once. Permissions are otherwise stored on Profiles, but those have historically been between difficult and impossible to deploy. That's why PermissionSets exist)


Thank you very much for your detailed response. It seems like a lot of effort went into writing your answer. I will try to learn and proceed with the work using the method you provided. Without your guidance, I wouldn't have been able to learn about Salesforce CLI so quickly. Have a great day!

ChatGPT has failed to mention that you need to deploy this code in order to to use the MetadataService class. This class isn't part of the standard Apex Code library. In general, be careful when using ChatGPT to help you program, as it often produces incorrect code, sometimes in the wrong programming language, or is otherwise incorrect. Make sure you test your code properly before deploying it to production.

Thank you very much for your sincere response. I also appreciate your advice on the importance of testing for stability.
